# react expo [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity.]

Tags: android, reactjs

I followed the tutorial for react native camera. I did all the changes also implemented the PermissionAwareActivity for MainActivity, but still give me [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity.]

**MainActivity.java**

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionAwareActivity;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionListener;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity implements PermissionAwareActivity {

    @Nullable
    private PermissionListener permissionListener;

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "AppCamera";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener) {
        permissionListener = listener;
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (permissionListener != null) {
            permissionListener.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```